# Is there any way to access Google's data on user preferences?

Tags: php, api

I want to build a customized news site (I know there's already thousands of them out there). However, I want to make the initial homepage relevant to the user. Google already has a huge database of user information, is there an API to access that?

Or, is there any way to find clues as to what the user likes? I just need general topics like technology, finance, sports, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

Do you really think that *as a user*, I'd like to have any websites in the world knowing what Google already knows about me? This kind of knowledge are *Facebook* and *Google* businesses and will they share that with you for nothing? Or maybe for some money, a lot of money I guess.

Your users will tell you what they like, just ask them.